# Completely Disable Formatting and Completion in ReSharper for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formatting, resharper, intellisense, resharper-6.0

I like a lot of the features that ReSharper offers, but I absolutely can't stand the formatting and code completion it does.  It trips me up every step of the way.  In javascript it's constantly stealing braces attempting to reformat my code making it not work, and hard to find where pieces are missing.

I would like to disable everything to do with ReSharper's formatting and code completion while still getting the benefits of the cool navigation stuff it has.

Is there anyway to do a selective install of ReSharper? I've tried disabling this stuff in the options but it doesn't seem to do any good.

Comment: You could also set ReSharper up to do formatting the way you want it...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Go to ReSharper | Options. Change the following options:

On the page Environment | Editor | Behavior: turn off options that starts from "Auto-format" or "Auto-insert". This won't disable ReSharper formatting features completely, but at least they won't be invoked automatically when typing.

On the page Intellisense | General: change to "Visual Studio". Or, if you only dislike code completion in JavaScript, change to "Limited ReSharper Intellisense" and turn off JavaScript.

P.S. Could you please describe with examples, what do you type when ReSharper is "stealing braces". Thanks!

Comment: Here is a video of what I'm talking about.  The brace at the bottom is for the containing function.  When starting a new one it steals it on completion.  I fixed it by disabling "Auto-insert closing brace".

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vu48htYFG7U

Even with this enabled, it still doesn't work as specified. The two options are On typing an opening brace, and On enter after an opening brace.  It doesn't seem to do either until I try to type my own closing brace, thats when it steals the other one.

Comment: I think it would be really cool of you guys to have one big button that says "disable all formatting and auto completion." Thank you for the reply regardless, I think I'm in a better spot now.

Comment: @ChrisLees It should steal closing brace only if it doesn't have matching open brace. Has your closing brace a matching open one?

Comment: Better than a big button...a big toggle button. That way, I could just turn it off when it's being a nasty, noisey little roadblock to my efficiency, and then back on when I actually want its help. PLEASE PLEASE PRETTY PLEASE.

Answer (score 11):

This will be heresy to some but I dislike Resharper's autocompletion and other intellisense items.   I turned them off but doing so left my normal VisualStudio Intellisense and ParameterInfo totally inactive.  Which I assume leads people to go back to Resharper because what's worse than bad is nothing.

If you need to turn off the Resharper part its pretty straight forward:

Resharper > Options > IntelliSense > **Select Visual Studio radio button**

Being I dislike this (possibly unintentional) coercion I decided to answer here how to recativate normal Visual Studio intellisense and parameter info this is how to get it back.

Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C# (for instance) > General > **Auto list members**

Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C# (for instance) > General > **Tick on Parameter information**

Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C# (for instance) > IntelliSense **Tick on Show completion list after a character is typed**

Comment: Thanks was vital. Thank you! If I remember correctly, this happened to me even after uninstalling Resharper, leaving Visual Studio thoroughly cripped.

Answer (score 0):

After not being able to find the offending setting in ReSharper's options (2018.1.3) I found it in Visual Studio's (2017) options:

- Text Editor

  - All Languages

    - General, Automatic brace completion